# Publish&install a package to Github using Pipenv and setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, setup.py, pipenv

I am trying to publish a **private package** using **Pipenv** to **Github**, and then install it in another project.

This is the folder structure of my package:

[image]

This is the `setup.py` file:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(name='sedricz', version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages(), zip_safe=False)
```

This is the publish command:

```sh
# Option 1
./setup.py bdist

# Option 2
./setup.py sdist
```

This is the installation command (terminal) on the second project:

```sh
# Option 1
pipenv install git+https://github.com/<git-project>.git@<branch>#egg=sedricz

# Option 2
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/<git-project>.git@<branch>#egg=sedricz
```

And the output of the installation:
[image]

Nonetheless, I only see a `sedricz-0.0.1.dist-info` under `site-packages` and I am unable to import the package.

Comment: So, everything is working as you think it should in terms of setting up the git repo, it's the pipenv install part, pulling your package back down from the git repo, and doing the actual install (reinstall) that is the issue?

Comment: I suspect both the distribution and the installation command.  1. I'm not sure what should be the artifacts of the distribution. 2. I'm not sure what is the purpose of the `egg` parameter.